# MVC custom error page enconding problems

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm implementing a custom error pages with Spring MVC for 404, 400 and 500 erros and I'm having encoding problems with jsp page.

I added in my web.xml file the action for error page:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404</location>
 </error-page>
```

I created  this class to handle the error:

```
package com.axa.cfrhealth.controller;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class HTTPErrorHandler{


 @RequestMapping(value="/400")
 public String error400(){
  System.out.println("custom error handler");
  return "400";
 }

 @RequestMapping(value="/404")
 public String error404(){
     //return new ResponseEntity<Object>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
     return "404";
 }

 @RequestMapping(value="/500")
 public String error500(){
  System.out.println("custom error handler");
  return "500";
 }


}
```

And finally I created 404.jsp page:

```
    <!-- INCLUDES -->
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    </head>

    <body>
      djhfakjhfkahakjf
    </body>

    </html>
```

But when I forced the 404 error to check that the custom page it is apperaring this is the error that I'm having in Chrome:

ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED.

Checking with Fiddler it seems that Chrome it is finding the page because from inspector I can see the page in TextView tab but it is not possible to see it in WebView tab, the message is "Response is encoded and require decoding before inspenction".

These are the request headers:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Cookie:JSESSIONID=75CD658DF19B2E6DB3EB12FD354E36C3
Host:localhost:8080
http_axa_mail:albert.martinez.altran@axa-groupsolutions.com
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36
```

And response headers:

```
Cache-control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-control:post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:429
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 13 Oct 2015 09:15:20 GMT
Expires:Sat, 6 May 1995 12:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

It seems that both compression(gzip) and charset(UTF-8) are correct, but even so the browser is reporting the encoding error instead of shows the custom error page... can someone help me, please?.

Regards.